# Getting PostCSS error when I add DaisyUI in the React Vite Project

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite, postcss, daisyui

I'm getting an issue when I try to add DaisyUI to my React Vite project.

This is in the terminal:

```
[vite] Internal server error: [postcss] Object.hasOwn is not a function
```

**This is in the browser:**

```
[plugin:vite:css] [postcss] Object.hasOwn is not a function
```

If I remove DaisyUI from the tailwind.config file then everything is perfect.

How can I solve this?

**My package.json file:**

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "daisyui": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.27",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you could be running a version of Node.js that is not supported by Daisy UI. If we look at [Daisy UI's `package.json` for the newest version, `v3.5.0`](https://github.com/saadeghi/daisyui/blob/v3.5.0/package.json#L46):

```json
"engines": {
  "node": ">=16.9.0"
},
```

This may be because `Object.hasOwn` does not exist in Node.js in versions lower than `16.9.0`, [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn#browser_compatibility).

To solve your problem, you could consider:

- Upgrading your version of Node.js to one greater than or equal to `16.9.0`.
- Using an older version of Daisy UI that supports your version of Node.js.

Comment: Thanks! You saved me. Yes, I was using node 14. After changing the version with nvm use 18 it's working fine.

Comment: then question and the answer was the exact thing that i need. You Both saved my day Guys. after changing my node version to 18.16.1 everything work fine.